# how to create carousel with size 80*60?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel and I wanted my carousel size became 80*60.how I can do it?

```
<div id="mycarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="IMG1.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="IMG2.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="IMG3.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can wrap it in a small block 80 x 60*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/bHdeZhS30z

**HTML**

```
<div class="small-block">
  <div id="mycarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
              <img src="IMG1.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="IMG2.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
              <img src="IMG3.png" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.small-block{
    width:80px;
    height:60px;
    background: cyan;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner{
  width:80px;
  height:60px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.carousel-inner img{
  width:80px;
  height:auto;
}
```